# How to get Date from Week Number, Year and dayOfWeek in java?

Tags: java, date

I have the week number, its curresponding year and dayOfWeek number(i.e. 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday and so on). Is there a way to find the date with this information in java?

Following is a method I found online.

```
int week = 51;
LocalDate wkstart = LocalDate.now().with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, week);
LocalDate mon = wks.plusDays(1);
LocalDate tue = wks.plusDays(2);
LocalDate wed = wks.plusDays(3);
LocalDate thu = wks.plusDays(4);
LocalDate fri = wks.plusDays(5);
LocalDate sat = wks.plusDays(6);
LocalDate wkend = wks.plusDays(7);
```

But then realised that wkstart is storing the current date instead of the start of the week.
Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of *adding* a number of days to `wkstart`, use `with` again to set the day of week. For example:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now()
    .with(WeekFields.ISO.weekBasedYear(), 2018) // year
    .with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 51) // week of year
    .with(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getValue()); // day of week
```

Comment: @OleV.V. You're right. Why not `WeekFields.ISO.weekBasedYear()` just to be consistent with the other fields though? There seems to be very little difference between the two... (I chose `WeekFields.ISO` because I don't like to see caps all over the place)

Comment: I don’t like any shouting in my code either. :-) Also `WeekFields.ISO` lends itself better to modification in case someone wants to define weeks differently.

Answer (score 8):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDate localDate = 
        YearWeek               // Represent an entire week of a week-based year per the ISO 8601 standard definition of a week.
        .of(                   // Instantiate a `YearWeek` object.
            2019 ,             // Specify the week-based year number, NOT the calendar year.
            51                 // Specify the week number, 1-52 or 1-53. 
        )
        .atDay(
            DayOfWeek.of( 1 )  // The value 1 yields a `DayOfWeek.MONDAY` object.
        )
;
```

## `org.threeten.extra.YearWeek`

The [Answer by Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59385769/642706) looks correct. But there is a more specialized class for this.

If doing much work with weeks of week-based years per the [ISO 8601 definition of week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), use the [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library. This library adds extra functionality to the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Determine the week.

```
YearWeek yearWeek = YearWeek.of( 2019 , 51 ) ;
```

Get a `LocalDate` for the day-of-week within that week.

```
LocalDate localDate = yearWeek.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
```

For the day-of-week, you should be using [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum objects in your code rather than mere integer numbers. To get a `DayOfWeek` from an original number 1-7 for Monday-Sunday, call `DayOfWeek.of( x )`.

```
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.of( 1 ) ;  // 1 = Monday, 7 = Sunday.
```

Putting that all together we get this one-liner.

```
LocalDate localDate = YearWeek.of( 2019 , 51 ).atDay( DayOfWeek.of( 1 ) ) ;
```

To be clear… The ISO 8601 definition of a week is:

- Week # 1 contains the first Thursday of the year.
- Weeks start on a Monday, ending on a Sunday.
- A year has either 52 or 53 complete 7-day weeks.
- The first/last weeks of the week-based year may contain the trailing/leading days of the previous/next calendar years. Thus, the calendar year of those days differ from the week-based year.

Answer (score 3):

## It also depends on the `Locale`.

Note that the ***first day of the week*** is `Locale`-dependent e.g. it is Monday in the UK while Sunday in the US. As per the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standards, it is Monday. For comparison, check the [US calendar](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2021&country=1&wno=1) and the [UK calendar](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2021&country=9&wno=1). Accordingly, the date will vary as shown in the example below:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        int weekNumber = 34;
        int year = 2021;
        
        System.out.println(getLocalDate(weekNumber, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, year, Locale.UK));
        System.out.println(getLocalDate(weekNumber, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, year, Locale.US));
        
        System.out.println(getLocalDate(weekNumber, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, year, Locale.UK));
        System.out.println(getLocalDate(weekNumber, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, year, Locale.US));        
    }

    static LocalDate getLocalDate(int weekNumber, DayOfWeek dow, int year, Locale locale) {
        return LocalDate.of(year, 2, 1)
                .with(dow)
                .with(WeekFields.of(locale).weekOfWeekBasedYear(), weekNumber);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-08-24
2021-08-17
2021-08-29
2021-08-15
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/MJmXfT)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>